# Is there a way to run two instances of Visual Studio side by side with different extensions and settings?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I would like to spend some time comparing the Visual Studio development experience with and without different combinations of extensions.  Specifically I want to establish how much value I am still getting out of Resharper and this involves trying to reproduce the Resharper experience as closely as possible by using alternative extensions, settings and keyboard shortcuts.

Please note I'm aware that there are many discussions on this topic online such as [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/amc6sx/do_you_feel_resharper_is_still_worth_using_in_2019/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/dotnet/comments/8k80vn/anyone_else_using_vs_intellicode_i_turned_off/) but I would like to test this for myself.

To do this I would like to be able to run two instances of the *same version* of Visual Studio on the same machine at the same time.  One using Resharper and one with an experimental configuration.

I have tried the approach suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841824/instances-of-visual-studio-with-different-settings) but I notice that it doesn't seem to prevent some extensions (Ncrunch and OzCode) from appearing in the new instance so I'm suspicious of how much isolation I'm really getting.

Also, as soon as I start up the new instance I'm automatically logged in and my shared profile settings are applied.  (I'm willing to set up a test profile for this exercise but it would be a bonus to be able to avoid having to do this.)

Is there a way to accomplish this or is the only real strategy here to use a different profile and a new installation on a different machine?

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper can be installed into experimental instance of Visual Studio, see section "Installing into experimental instance of Visual Studio" here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Installation_Guide.html