Can a VIsual Studio extension be installed only for one project?
I'm working w/ a client who wants all developers to install a Visual Studio extension (XAML style in this case). I don't want this extension to effect all my projects. Short of creating a new user to login as (if that works), can a VStud extension be enabled by project by project/solution?

Possible duplicate of How to disable a Visual Studio extension for a specific solution?

The short answer is no: VS extensions are loaded outside of any project context. But you can use another extension that manages your extensions for you, but disabling/enabling extensions requires restarting VS.

Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "Visual Studio extension (XAML style)"? A VS extension is not how XAML styles/resources should be redistributed (it should be using NuGet or similar). Assuming your post is accurate, then it means the author of this extension is going about this the entirely wrong way...

yes, kind of reverse but not exactly a duplicate @PeterB thanks. I'll consider that.

@Dai simple a Visual Studio extension .... this one does XAML style checks/fixes. Sounds like NO and thanks.

@kenny That sounds like something that could be repackaged as a Code Analysis package using NuGet.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49841824/instances-of-visual-studio-with-different-settings

@SergeyVlasov IMO that looked like that answer, but when I ran those command line arguments on a up to date 2022, the extensions came installed. I I'm going to look more, maybe there's an answer that way.

For reference anyone visiting, there are many flags to set.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

More stuff to look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/import-export-installation-configurations?view=vs-2022

I have dropped it ... I found out I can run that XAML Style tool installed as a .NET tool. https://github.com/Xavalon/XamlStyler/wiki/Script-Integration
I think there's an answer to use command line arguments @ VStud startup


Can a VIsual Studio extension be installed only for one project?

I'm afraid not. By default, Visual Studio installs extensions globally, meaning they are available across all projects and solutions. However, as you mentioned above, "Short of creating a new user to login as (if that works),", i think creating a new user may work.
Most extensions are per-user extensions and are installed in the %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<Visual Studio version>\Extensions\ folder.
A few extensions are administrative extensions and are installed in the <Visual Studio installation folder>\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ folder.
So when you change an account for Windows, extensions from your previous account will not be loaded in the current Visual Studio.
Login in with Account A and install this Visual Studio extension (XAML style in this case) to your project.
Login in with Account B and check if this extension has been installed.
Besides, if you consider installing multiple Visual Studio Instances, you can install this specific extension on VS2022 Community but not for VS2022 Profession.
Docs Referred:
Per-user and administrative extensions
